# Cannot import matplotlib.pylot on my mac

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pip, virtualenv

So I am stuck on this frustrating issue on my mac OSX: I basically get the following error when I run this import:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

I am using Python 2.7.10, on Mac OSX (10.11.1), and I am in an virtual-environment.

I have looked at a bunch of posts that talk about `_tkinter`, and I have tried to install it via `pip install python-tk`, but it says that no such module exists... I am at a loss for how to get my matplotlib working in my Mac!

**EDIT: The full error message:**

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> /Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py:273: UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.
  warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 114, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from matplotlib.externals.six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 199, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 113, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Users/billy/venv/tf012/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/externals/six.py", line 80, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/opt/original/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

Comment: are you sure you're using the same 2.7 version? because _tkinter is installed by default on 2.7

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I think so - when I run python, that is what it says the version number is...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I edited the question with the full error message.

Comment: have you tried: `pip install tkinter`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "sudo -H pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tkinter"

Answer (score 0):

Almost the same thing happened to me when I tried installing matplotlib. Try using 3.4 and install it on Anaconda before hand.

Comment: I'd rather not go to 3.4. But how do you mean install "on Anaconda"? I am in a virtualenv...

Comment: I use a linux computer, and there's this python installer called "anaconda" or "miniconda" that you can [probably] install _tkinter. Also, do you have numpy installed? (Also, you can search up Anaconda here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: Okay - I think you need to find tkinter on anaconda and install it, i'm not sure

Comment: There's also this but I'm not sure about it - https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/

Comment: So interestingly enough, I got this working if i made my virtualenv INSIDE the /anaconda2/envs folder I have. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: Nope - this is getting out of my area ;)

Comment: Or maybe it's because it didn't recognize anaconda otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to get back to coding with minimal fuss, what I ended up doing in the end was this:

- I already had an /anaconda2/envs directory, since (I think) I installed python on my Mac via anaconda at some point.
- Anaconda is apparently not compatible with virtualenv, so I abandoned using virtualenv for my Mac.
- I simply created an environment via **conda** , (and not **virtualenv**). (Via: `conda create -n myAwesomeEnv python=2.7.11`
- I activate my new env, via: `source activate ~/anaconda2/envs/myAwesomeEnv/`
- I install matplotlib via `pip install matplotlib`
- Now the above matplotlib commands in the question work without issue.